# Автоматическое выпадание datalist

Tags: javascript, html, input, события, datalist

Есть задача - имитация `select` с помощью `datalist` и кнопки.

Суть - кликаешь на кнопку - появляется список подсказок (как при автозаполнении).

Проблема - при клике на кнопку input получает фокус, но потом не хочет показывать выпадающие подсказки!

```js
document.querySelector("#subject > button").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = document.querySelector("#subject > input");
  input.focus();
  var event = new Event("click");
  input.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

```html
<label id="subject">
  <input name="subject" type="text" class="in-bl-el" placeholder="your subject" list="subjects" autocomplete="off">
  <button>btn</button>
</label>
<datalist id="subjects">
  <option>Subject 1</option>
  <option>Subject 2</option>
  <option>Subject 3</option>
  <option>Subject 4</option>
  <option>Subject 5</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Посмотрите http://jsbin.com/urupit/4/watch?html,js,output .Возможно поможет

Comment: ну это ж имитация) трюк с div'ом - это не то...

Comment: А Вы тогда делайте под `datalist`'ом `<select>` или кнопки, на которых будут значения. И после нажатия на кнопку скрывать кнопки некого класса `х`. Затем в `input` забивайте значение, которое было на кнопке.

Comment: тогда уже проще обычный select сделать))

Comment: Или там надо симитировать dblclick

Comment: https://www.ria.com/objavlenie/ Вот тут есть Тип доставки. Посмотрите. Может быть такой вариант Вас интересует

Comment: не работает ни двойной клик, ни клик на label (инпут по умолчанию должен фокус получать при клике, но не получает), ни клавиша "вниз"